# Wordpress, blog-page dont show blogs

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I merge wordpress with bootstrap and i want get something like this:

```
1|
 | 2
3|
```

I check if there is post (there is 3 at that moment). Next is loop and showing the blogs... But its show empty boxes...

What i done wrong ? 
Or maybe there is better way to do this?

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <?php
        $rest_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => array('post'),
            'post_status' => 'publish'
    ));

  if($rest_query->have_posts()):
    ?>

    <?php while($rest_query->have_posts()): $rest_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
        if ($rest_query->current_post == 0)
        { 
            echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="single first-post">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div></a>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                        <div class="data">
                            <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date();s ?></p>
                            <p class="social">0 shares / 0 comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middleLine"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>';
        } 
        elseif ($rest_query->current_post == 1)
        { echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="middleLine"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="single secound-post">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div></a>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                            <div class="data">
                                <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date();s ?></p>
                                <p class="social">0 shares / 0 comments</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>'; } 
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you code has some error while showing in the page. While you use ECHO you should not use PHP tag inside it which is why it is not working in your case.

Revising your code:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<?php
    $rest_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'post_status' => 'publish'
));

if($rest_query->have_posts()):
?>

<?php while($rest_query->have_posts()): $rest_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php 
    if ($rest_query->current_post == 0)
    { 
        echo '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="single first-post">
                <a href="'.the_permalink().'"><div class="thumb">'.the_post_thumbnail().'</div></a>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="'.the_permalink().'"><h1>'.the_title().'</h1></a>
                    <div class="data">
                        <p class="date">'.get_the_date().'</p>
                        <p class="social">0 shares / 0 comments</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middleLine"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>';
    } 
    elseif ($rest_query->current_post == 1)
    { echo '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="middleLine"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="single secound-post">
                    <a href="'.the_permalink().'"><div class="thumb">'.the_post_thumbnail().'</div></a>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="'.the_permalink().'"><h1>'.the_title().'</h1></a>
                        <div class="data">
                            <p class="date">'.get_the_date().'</p>
                            <p class="social">0 shares / 0 comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>'; } 
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

NOTE: If you want to print any PHP variable then it should be used as i have have shown above code.

THank you